# Get Exact Age based on Date Today VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have here a `vb.net` code that get the age but it does not print actual date
for example: Today is June 4,2020 and my birthday is June 5,1998 the age output will be 22 even the right age is 21:
Please see code below for reference

```
Dim birthday As String = "06/05/1998"
birthday = Format(DateValue(birthday), "MM/dd/yyyy")
Response.Write(DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateValue(birthday), Now()) / 12)


'Output : 22
```

Comment: How do you know `"06/05/1998"` isn't May 6th 1998? Date and time values are not their string representations....

Comment: I just used it as example , but in my code it is formatted to "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: I edited my sample code and added the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Private Function GetAge(dateOfBirth As Date) As Integer
    dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth.Date

    Dim age = CInt(DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, dateOfBirth, Date.Today))

    dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth.AddYears(age)

    If dateOfBirth > Date.Today Then
        age -= 1
    End If

    Return age
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim birthday As Date = CDate("06/04/1998")

    Dim year As Byte = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, birthday, Now())

    If Now.Month > birthday.Month Then
        year -= 1
    ElseIf Now.Month = birthday.Month And Now.Date > birthday.Date Then
        year -= 1
    End If
    Response.Write(year)
```

Comment: I edited my question and change the birthday to June 5, 2020 same output